# Android VideoView looping with blending

Tags: android, android-videoview

Is there a possibility to loop an Android VideoView with a more seamless transition, i.e. blending from the last couple of frames to the first ones?

I prefer to achieve the effect *without* using a TextureView-backed playback but it might only be possible with them.